# Docker Embedded DNS returns truncated domain name when doing reverse ns lookup

Tags: domain-name-system, docker

I've been trying to setup domain name inside a container and check how the embedded Docker DNS deals with those settings.
But I was surprised to see that I was only given a truncated domain name when doing reverse ns lookup.

I set the fqdn to be like `ldec<i>.n18.org`
The command `hostname --fqdn` inside the container returned me `ldec1.n18.org` as expected, the ping `ping ldec1.n18.org` is working as expected with fqdn properly resolved.

But if I do a reverse ns lookup like `dig -x <container_ip>`, I am always returned with a truncated domain name like `ldec3.n18` instead of `ldec3.n18.org`.

```
root@ldec3:/# dig -x 172.18.0.4

; <<>> DiG 9.16.37-Debian <<>> -x 172.18.0.4 
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 21081
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;4.0.18.172.in-addr.arpa.       IN      PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
4.0.18.172.in-addr.arpa. 600    IN      PTR     ldec3.n18.

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.11#53(127.0.0.11)
;; WHEN: Mon Apr 17 18:59:38 UTC 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 87
```

**So why dig returns me a truncated domain name ?**

To build the image

```bash
docker build --tag=debian:11-lde - <<EOF
FROM debian:11

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive 

ENV APT_CMD="apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends"
# SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-x", "-c"]

RUN echo "===> Add tools..."  \
  && apt-get update  \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    iputils-ping bind9-dnsutils lsof \
    openssh-*   \
    wget curl  \
    iptables whois iproute2 net-tools \
    vim less sudo bash-completion patch \
    ca-certificates \
  && apt-get autoremove -y \
  && echo OK
EOF
```

To start the 3 containers on the same network

```bash
docker network create --driver=bridge n18 --subnet=172.18.0.0/24 || true

for i in $(seq 1 1 3)
do
  docker rm -f "ldec${i}" || true
  declare domain="n18.org"
  docker run --interactive --tty --detach --rm --name "ldec${i}" \
            --network=n18 --hostname="ldec${i}.${domain}" \
            --dns="8.8.8.8" \
            debian:11-lde
done
```

Comment: To the person who down-voted, I would have appreciated a comment to point out the glaring mistake that justified it. I admit being a nube on anything dns related.

Comment: `dig` displays whatever the nameserver gave to it, so check the nameserver zonefile, you probably add an extra dot that made the name absolute, where removing it will make it relative again to the zone in which it sits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I tested with Podman V3 along with the dnsname plugin and with dnsmasq on the host and at last I got what I was expecting

```
...
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;4.0.5.192.in-addr.arpa.                IN      PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
4.0.5.192.in-addr.arpa. 0       IN      PTR     ldec3.newnet.podman.
...
```

So it seems Docker's internal DNS has a very specific/opinionated way of answering reverse DNS requests and if you need a more conventionnal DNS behavior, to test your ansible roles dealing with network configurations etc..., you might be better off using Podman V3 or trying to shunt Docker's internal DNS and use something like dnsmasq or bind9.

Check also this related thread on SO that explains: [how-can-i-give-docker-containers-access-to-a-dnsmasq-local-dns-resolver-on-the-h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35693117/how-can-i-give-docker-containers-access-to-a-dnsmasq-local-dns-resolver-on-the-h).

**EDIT2:** Docker's Embedded DNS

Reverse DNS queries on hosts inside a custom networks is 'peculiar' and Docker won't let you disable their embedded DNS (dates back to 2017):

- https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26298#issuecomment-339126461
- https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/19474#issuecomment-335253478

So in 2023, you are still left with workarounds with /etc/resolv and /etc/hosts or patching the code to disable the ES.